# How do I remove dashboard access from specific user roles?

Tags: admin, user-roles, dashboard

I'd like to prevent certain user roles from accessing the dashboard http://www.openeye.net/wp-admin/ at all. I've moved and restyled user profiles to a new page that's viewable on the site. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I requested WooCommerce to change their setup, so it is possible to manage authorisations for their part of the menu. The idea needs votes on: [https://ideas.woocommerce.com](https://ideas.woocommerce.com/forums/133476-woocommerce/suggestions/39069922-woocommerce-should-not-reveal-an-overview-of-all-p) Please give it your maximum 3 points, thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To lock subscribers and contributors out of the admin:

```
function wpse23007_redirect(){
  if( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') && ( current_user_can('subscriber') || current_user_can('contributor') ) ){
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit;
  }
}
add_action('init','wpse23007_redirect');
```

Hope that helps. All roles give the user a capability that is the name of that role, so you can use any role name as a capability.

Comment: Excellent, however I'm getting a syntax error on the second line.

Comment: Oh ok it's related to the extra ( after ('DOING_AJAX')

Comment: Oh, sorry; that was intentional. There was supposed to be another one closing at the end. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Is there a reason this doesn't work with the 2011 theme and the members plugin?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on network sites, any idea why?

Comment: Seem to work for me, on a standard wordpress install. Thanks very much :-)

Comment: Ajax request on `admin-ajax.php` redirecting me to homepage. I am not on multisite.

Answer (score 3):

```
//If User Roll is Subscriber, It can not login in Dashboard 
function wpse23007_redirect()
{
    if( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') && current_user_can('subscriber') )
    {
        wp_logout();
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('init','wpse23007_redirect');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to use the current_user_can( $capability ) function. Here is the official WordPress reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

Answer (score 0):

```
 add_action('init', function(){

      $redirect = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : home_url( '/' );
      $user = wp_get_current_user();
      if ( !defined('DOING_AJAX') && in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {

          wp_redirect($redirect);
          exit();
      }
});
```