# WP Multisite with Domain Mapping : Preventing User Access to Dashboard

Tags: multisite, wp-admin

I have a theme being used by a sub-folder multisite and a domain-mapped multi site.

E.g.

mywpsite.com/site1

mywpsite.com/site2

www.site2.com (leads to the above)

I have this snippet of code in my functions.php file

```
function my_wp_admin_ban(){
if( !current_user_can('activate_plugins') ){
wp_redirect( get_bloginfo('url') );
exit;
}
}

add_action('admin_init','my_wp_admin_ban');
```

This successfully prevents members of site1 from access the admin (wp-admin) dashboard area.

This code does not, however, seem to work for site2.

Instead, those users are shown a "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." error message.

Tried everything I can think of including different ways of doing the same thing I.e. [How to redirect non admins to homepage if trying to view mysite.com/wp-admin/?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90535/how-to-redirect-non-admins-to-homepage-if-trying-to-view-mysite-com-wp-admin) and [How do I remove dashboard access from specific user roles?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23007/how-do-i-remove-dashboard-access-from-specific-user-roles)

What can I do to ensure all users (non admin) of the multisite are redirected away from the dashboard area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `functions.php` is not the place to run this kind of code. See [Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160/12615)

You can use a [Must Use plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) or make a simple one and *Network Activate*.

It would go like this:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Only admins on dashboard */

add_action( 'admin_init', 'admin_ban_wpse_105863' );

function admin_ban_wpse_105863()
{
    if( !current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ){
        wp_redirect( site_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

The [documentation for the function `get_bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) has recommended alternatives for many cases. The `site_url` function takes care of using the current blog URL.

---

**[update]**
The only place where the error message *`...permissions to access...`* appears is in the file [`wp-admin/includes/menu.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-admin/includes/menu.php#L226). And it has an useful hook:

```
add_action( 'admin_page_access_denied', 'denied_ban_wpse_105863' );

function denied_ban_wpse_105863()
{
    wp_redirect( site_url() );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Created a plugin instead and removed the offending code from functions.php Still gives the same message for site2 "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

Comment: Did you tried as a mu-plugin? I tested in my two local MS installations (subdomain and subdirectory) and it works ok.

Comment: I did. It doesnt work. Are you using sunrise on any of them? Im sure that has something to do with it.

Comment: I just tested in a live site with sunrise, and it worked as well :/ If possible, try to disable the other plugins. Or try another capability. I'll add an alternative in the Answer.

Comment: Would you believe, for reasons unknown, I need both snippets of code. The 'admin_init' for sites like site1 and the 'admin_page_access_denied' for sites like site2. Thanks to you brasofilo!